# onvif open iris in C# using wsdl

Tags: c#, wsdl, onvif

I read that http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl is required to control focus and iris.

I was able to control the focus with the following code:

```
    FocusMove ifm = new FocusMove();
    RelativeFocus irf = new RelativeFocus();
    FocusMove dfm = new FocusMove();
    RelativeFocus drf = new RelativeFocus();
    irf.Distance = 0.1F;
    ifm.Relative = irf;
    drf.Distance = -0.1F;
    dfm.Relative = drf;

    private void btnIncFocus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imagingPortClient.Move(videoSource, ifm);
    }

    private void btnDecFocus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imagingPortClient.Move(videoSource, dfm);
    }
```

The above code works great. Now I need to be able to open and close the iris. However, unlike the focus control which has imagingPortClient.Move method, there does not seem to have a similar method for iris control.

Any pointers is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: There's `SetImagingSettings` (https://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl/imaging.wsdl#op.SetImagingSettings) where you can find `tt:Exposure/tt:Iris` field. I do set it, and I do get changed value from `GetImagingSettings` afterwards, but I do not see any changes in video output... (with some Dahua camera, not using C#, but Python with zeep package to generate ONVIF requests).